# Nuxt3 default error page can't be overwritten with layouts/error.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I have created a layouts/error.vue file that I'd like to use as my error page in my Nuxt3 app.

But for some reason, the default error page keeps loading up every time.

This is the default error page:[image: default nuxt3 error page]

This is the code I have in my error.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["error"],
};
</script>
```

Every developer I have seen so far or read the docs explains this as a pretty simple thing to do by creating a folder and a file, so this might have to do something with my setup tho.

Anyway, could any of you point me to the right direction here please?

Comment: Did you restart your nuxt app?

Comment: Yes, a couple million times, just to make sure, but still wasn't showing up :S

Comment: "You can customize this error page by adding ~/error.vue in the source directory of your application, alongside app.vue. This page has a single prop - error which contains an error for you to handle." You have yours in layouts folder maybe that's the case

Comment: This was the solution, thanks! The only thing I can't understand now is which part I was doing wrong when I was going with the documentation solution "You can customize the error page by adding a layouts/error.vue file"
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts/#layouts-directory

Comment: This is for Nuxt 2 since Nuxt 3 is still in Beta release the authors need to have both documentations

Comment: Great, thanks again!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created `error` file in `layouts` folder which stands for Nuxt version 2.

For Nuxt 3 you need to keep it next to app.vue file in your root folder. As documentation says:

> You can customize this error page by adding ~/error.vue in the source directory of your application, alongside app.vue. This page has a single prop - error which contains an error for you to handle.

Comment: Is this behaviour configurable ? Maybe via `nuxt.config.js` ?

Comment: Read this page: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#rendering-errors-within-your-app